# #SNMP No contextName in V3 response

Tags: sharp-snmp

We are using #SNMP to created an SNMP V3 agent.

I would like to know if it is normal that the SecureSnmpContext class does not use the given ContextName when using GeneratedResponse for example ?

The ContextName is available into the request object ?

In the code, `OctetString.Empty` is used instead of ContextName.

```
new Scope(Group.EngineId,
                    OctetString.Empty,
                    new ResponsePdu(
                        Request.RequestId(),
                        ErrorCode.NoError,
                        0,
                        variables)),
```

Is the ContextName not required in the response maybe ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The design of the snmpd sample follows Net-SNMP agent, which does not use the context name much.

If you have requirements to set that field, feel free to modify the code base to suit your needs please.

Remember that you also need to modify the authentication part to verify context name of the incoming messages if you do set a context name.